# Re run angular filter on scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The application I'm building has an option for Users to change the unit distances between kilometers and miles.

I've build a small filter to convert those distances:

```
app.filter('distance', function() {

    return function(input, scope) {
        var distanceName = (scope.units.distance === 'km') ? 'km' : 'ml';

        // scope.units.value is 1000 by default and 621 if miles are selected.
        return (input / scope.units.value).toFixed(2) + distanceName;
    };

});
```

In my template I use it simply like that:

```
{{ point.distance | distance }}
```

The issue is when the `$scope.units.value` change the filter do not update the value, I should re run the filter in someway... Even if I expect it to be done by Angular, but it doesn't.

When the value change the digest is started so if I force it with `$scope.$apply()` it fire an error.

How can I solve it, what I'm missing for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second (and consequent) input arguments to a filter are specified using the colon `:` operators. 
Right now you're not specifying a second argument to your filter.

`points.distance` is the input argument, arguments specified after colons are the rest of the possible parameters.

So in your case `units.distance` maps to `scope` on your filter, which is a confusing name, consider changing it to `measurement` or something like that

For your filter to work you also need `units.value`. Add an additional parameter to your filter `return function(input, measurement, value) ...` and use it like so

```
{{ point.distance | distance:units.distance:units.value }}
```

EDIT: Like @charlietfl mentioned, a simpler solution would probably be:

`return function(input, measurementConfig) ...`

Usage:

`{{ point.distance | distance:units }}`

Comment: Could have simply added units object in view `{{ point.distance | distance :units }}`

Comment: Aren't the filter view arguments reference watches?

Comment: Looks like they're deep watches, I'll update the answer